# Facebook sharing from my app crashes on Motorola Droid?

Tags: android

I have developed an app that allows to post data on the facebook wall using facebook sdk.I have tested on a few other phones like LG optimus but when the app runs on the motorola droid it crashes at times.

When i click on the share facebook button in my context menu the app crashes.

I have googled and found out this much

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/92d6f063682d2ca4/735acce1300115d7?show_docid=735acce1300115d7&pli=1.

There is a problem with Droid phones when using web kit.

The same issue was reported on facebook sdk 
  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/82?authenticity_token=a321076df454835ad9c481d6fa73a3ea8cad1ceb

Again it is mostly said that the exception has occurred during the use of motorola droid.

Here is the stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged(WebView.java:4177)
    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does someone have a solution or workaround to this?

Edit:This seems to be happening on HTC Incredible also.

Comment: Does anybody find any solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 7):

There is a work around for this which explicitly mentions the Motorola Droid you can find the original posting at:

[Workaround for Null Pointer Excpetion in WebView.onWindowFocusChanged](http://www.zubha-labs.com/workaround-for-null-pointer-excpetion-in-webv)

Create a custom webclass:

[CustomWebView.java](https://gist.github.com/1054898)

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        try{
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
        // Catch null pointer exception
        }
    }
}
```

Now open up the FbDialog.java provided by facebook and modify the line that creates the webview to use the the CustomWebView subclass as follows

`WebView view = new CustomWebView(getContext());`

Comment: Thanks a lot .Gonna test it and will let you know

Comment: Hi @Merlin, I'm also facing the same problem, but where do I need to place "WebView view = new CustomWebView(getContext());" this code.
I'm using "facebookConnector.login();", it is automatically opening a embedded facebook logiin screen.

Comment: Odl topic but since the Venkat's question also bothered us and there's nothing in the internet. Modify the file FbDialog.java provided by facebook (package: com.facebook.android). CTRL+F for "new WebView" and you'll find the line where you've to call the CustomWebView.

Comment: @yoshi I have updated this answer, I was probably in a stress ball when I originally answered this so I didn't follow it up.  I hope this makes amends.

Comment: What you're talking about? I just see a good answer. :) *thumbs up* http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png